# Trying to pass a list from servlet to jsp but prints null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList` of objects from a servlet to a jsp file but when I try printing it, it prints nothing. I used the exact lines from a similar post for the jsp...can someone help me because I have never used a jsp before.
The idea is to to traverse through an xml file using dom parser and then  print its elements to an html table of a specific form. My java code successfully collects all the elements and stores them in a list which I want to pass in the jsp to format in the table asked...

**SERVLET CODE** (with missing pieces cause it's huge) :

```
import all the needed libraries

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    private static xml_obj obj = null;
    public static ArrayList<xml_obj> objList = new ArrayList<xml_obj>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Start(); //starting the methods for the xml traversal and creates the list
            //System.out.println("AA"+objList.get(1).getName());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {  
        ArrayList list = getList();
        //System.out.println(objList.get(1).getName());
        request.setAttribute ("Xml_objList", objList );  
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("DomNav.jsp");  
        view.forward (request,response);          
    }       
    static void Start(){

                /*..........code missing.............*/
            myDOMTreeProc dtp = new myDOMTreeProc();
            dtp.processLvl(ListOfCh, 0); //processLvl -> method in myDOMTreeProc

    }

    public static ArrayList<xml_obj> getList() {
          return objList;
       }
}


class myDOMTreeProc {
 /*........DOM XML TRAVERSE.......*/
}

class attribute {
private String Name;
private String Value;

 /*.............setters/getters.......*/

}

class xml_obj {
   public int Lvl;
   private String Name;
   private String Value;
   private String Parent;
   private ArrayList<attribute> attributes=null;
   /*.............setters/getters.......*/
```

}

**JSP CODE:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Expression Language Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST JSP</h1>
<% ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("Xml_objList"); %>
 <c:forEach var="item" items="${Xml_objList}">
          ${item.Lvl}
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

The list is correct I tested it. I think the problem is when I pass it in the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [Java Naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html) and everything will work fine. Just replace `int Lvl` with `int lvl;`

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${Xml_objList}">
      ${item.lvl}
</c:forEach>
```

Instead of `${item.lvl}` you can try with `${item.getLvl()}` or `${item['lvl']}`

Comment: **Please leave the comments... Plzzzzzzzzzzz**

Comment: Not working...question do I need an xml file for this?

Comment: what is not working? `lvl` is an `int` variable. where are you using `list` defined here `<% ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("Xml_objList"); %>`

Comment: You don't need any any xml file. Simply store all the data in list in Servlet and iterate this list in JSP.